# CURLFile stops CURL from working, CURL Error 43

Tags: php, curl, post

I have a form to upload a ticket to a ticketing system, and I need the user to be able to pass attachments. As soon as I add a CURLFile to the POST, CURL seems to stop working. I added "error_log("foo") to the receiving file and nothing is logged, suggesting that the request doesn't even send.

My CURL code is:

```
$data = new CURLFile(
    $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][0],
    $_FILES['attachment']['type'][0],
    $_FILES['attachment']['name'][0]
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.0.56/api-test/foo.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'some_file' => $data
]);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

var_dump outputs: bool(false)

curl_errno outputs: 43

curl_error produces nothing

CURLOPT_VERBOSE and error($ch) outputs:

```
* Hostname 192.168.0.56 was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.0.56...
* Connected to 192.168.0.56 (192.168.0.56) port 80 (#0)
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.0.56 left intact
```

Comment: when debugging, use var_dump , not echo. when debugging curl, also use CURLOPT_VERBOSE and curl_errno() and curl_error(). fix those, get the results of both var_dump, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, and error($ch) , and come back

Comment: Hi @hanshenrik, that's done, see modified answer

Comment: hmm, interesting, 43 is `CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Internal error. A function was called with a bad parameter.` - add error detection to your curl_setopt's , like `function ecurl_setopt($ch,int $option,$value):bool{$ret=curl_setopt($ch,$option,$value);if(!$ret){throw new RuntimeException('curl_setopt failed. errno: '.curl_errno($ch).'. error: '.curl_error($ch));}return true;}` , and use that instead of curl_setopt, see if it fails somewhere

Comment: I've ran your code and none of them seem to throw the exception. This is exceptionally confusing. If I remove "'some_file' => $data" and replace it with "some_value => 1" the connection is made. I wonder if a permissions issue could occur somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who encounters this error in the future, permissions turned out to be the problem. I added a script to save the file to a folder (other than the temp folder as it would be on upload), and then ran the code above against that saved file, and it worked.